# Add multiple IN condition and rollup time period in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

```
SELECT  SUM (Sales_dollar_amt)
  FROM  srm.nielsen_pos_volumetric_causal_distribution_ca_weekly_combined AS A
 WHERE  A.product_long_desc IN ( 'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS 260GM', 'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT 330 GM', 'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT BOX 292GM',
    'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS MULTIGRAIN 265GM' ) --
    AND market_long_desc = 'LCL NATIONAL' --
    AND fiscal_week_end_dt = '2021-07-25 00:00:00';
```

The above query is working. but now I want to **add** 2 below items:

1. 5 more groups based on different combination of `product_long_desc`
2. I want to add a  year to date as well `where fiscal_week_end_dt from '2021-01-01 00:00:00' --'2021-07-25 00:00:00'`  as well in the same query

Can anyone help me out how to do that?

Comment: please provide sample data with table structure and expected output?

Comment: Wich database do yo use? MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server or SQLite? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69264195/edit) your question to remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Five more groups *of what*?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to add only product_long_desc and date range , you can modify it like :

Note : Below section is for product_long_desc to be added:

```
'first',  'second','third','forth', 'fifth'
```

Full query:

```
SELECT sum(Sales_dollar_amt)
  FROM srm.nielsen_pos_volumetric_causal_distribution_ca_weekly_combined AS A
 where
  A.product_long_desc in
       ('GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS 260GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT 330 GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT BOX 292GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS MULTIGRAIN 265GM',
        'first', 
        'second',
        'third',
        'forth',
        'fifth')
   and market_long_desc = 'LCL NATIONAL'
   and fiscal_week_end_dt between '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-25 00:00:00'
```

---

If you are going to do combination of  product_long_desc and market_long_desc , you should use **or and brackets**  :

```
   SELECT sum(Sales_dollar_amt)
  FROM srm.nielsen_pos_volumetric_causal_distribution_ca_weekly_combined AS A
 where
( ( A.product_long_desc in    
       ('GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS 260GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT 330 GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT BOX 292GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS MULTIGRAIN 265GM')
   and market_long_desc = 'LCL NATIONAL'
   ) or 
--1st group
 ( A.product_long_desc in
       ('GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS 260GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT 330 GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT BOX 292GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS MULTIGRAIN 265GM')
   and market_long_desc = 'LCL NATIONAL'
   ) or 
 -- 2nd group  
    ( A.product_long_desc in
       ('GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS 260GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT 330 GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS HONEY NUT BOX 292GM',
        'GENERAL MILLS CHEERIOS MULTIGRAIN 265GM')
   and market_long_desc = 'LCL NATIONAL'
   )
   
   -- and goes on ....
    
  ) 
   and fiscal_week_end_dt between '2021-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-25 00:00:00'
```

Comment: ....I think we can go ahead with the second approach. But any idea can we add alias for each of the group in sqlserver? if yes how

Comment: they are filter groups so i didnt undestand what do you mean by add alias